Fixed values but variable year
I have this two measures, the first one calculates the average sales of the full year and show it in my graph as a fixed value; the second one calculates and show the same but for the prior year.
Fixed= DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Sales], 50), ALL('DataMain')),
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[Month]), ALLEXCEPT('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year]))
)

FixedPriorYear = 
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( 
        DIVIDE([Sales], 20), 
        ALL ( 'DataMain' ),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR)
    ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Calendar'[Month]), 
        ALL ('Calendar'),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR)
    )
)

The problem that i want to solve is that, the averge is correctly calculated and displayed, but when i change the the year using a slicer, the average is not recalculating.
Data example year 2023:
| Month    | Sales          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| January  | 100            |
| February | 200            |
| March    | 300            |
| April    | 400            |
| May      | 500            |
| June     | 600            |
| July     | 700            |
| August   | 800            |
| September| 900            |
| October  | 1000           |
| November | 1100           |
| December | 1200           |

the sum of these values is 7800, the average is 650. With those measures i have the same result (650) to display it in each month. But when i change the year in my slicer, the result dont change.
Here´s a image to show what i have at the moment. I only need that when i change the year in my slicer, the average recalculate itself.


could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

i already edit it

This is the sample data I used for test.



year
month
Sales




2023
Jan
10


2023
Feb
20


2023
Mar
30


2023
Apr
40


2023
May
50


2023
Jun
60


2023
Jul
70


2023
Aug
80


2023
Sep
90


2023
Oct
100


2023
Nov
110


2023
Dec
120


2022
Jan
130


2022
Feb
140


2022
Mar
150


2022
Apr
160


2022
May
170


2022
Jun
180


2022
Jul
190


2022
Aug
200


2022
Sep
210


2022
Oct
220


2022
Nov
230


2022
Dec
240



you can create a measure
MEASURE =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[year] = MAX ( 'Table'[year] ) )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Table'[month] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[year] = MAX ( 'Table'[year] ) )
    )
)




It worked perfectly!! thank you so much!
